# What is the simple explanation for the fact that L1 norm gets increased faster around the origin than L2?'

Tags: machine-learning

L1 norm gets linearly increased around the origin while L2 norm doesn't( it does but at a slower rate)? Can anybody provide a simple explanation for this?
L2 norm is given by the square root of (x1^2+x2^2.....xn^2) where x1,x2....xn are the elements of the vector x.
L1 norm is just the summation of all the elements of vector x, that is, L1= x1+x2+x3......xn. 
I can't just understand why this happens by looking at those formulas?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "explanation" in this case (I strongly suggest you avoid the word significantly as well, since it has a specific meaning in statistics). If you're aware of how the functions are defined, then yes, the L2 norm increases "more slowly" in the immediate neighborhood of the minimum, but it's a consequence of the behavior of powers in the definition (given $L=|x-x_0|^p$, smaller powers increase faster than larger ones for very small $x-x_0$). What kind of explanation do you seek?

Comment: I was actually going through a course for mathematics in machine learning and that's where I heard this property that L1 norm gets linearly increased around the origin while L2 norm doesn't( it does but at a slower rate I guess) . Actually, it was an explanation of why L1 norms are used to discriminate between very small non-zero values and zero values. So I wondered why the L1 norm gets increases faster than L2 so that I can be clear with why L2 norms can't be used to discriminate between zero and very small non zero values?

Comment: It's no clearer what you're after. Is it that you don't know what the $L_1$ and $L_2$ loss functions are (just substitute $p=1$ and $p=2$ above) or that you don't understand how $L_p=|x-x_0|^p$ behaves when $p=1$ and $p=2$ for small $x-x_0$? (do you need help to draw them?) or is it something else?

Comment: The latter one. I don't know how it behaves when we put p=1 and p=2 in the formula above?

Comment: Thanks, Sir. Now I got it what you were trying to say. That's why the squared L2 norm increases more slowly around the origin than L2 norm. And the same goes with L1 norm and L2 norm. But I had this doubt, the formula you wrote for loss functions is different from actual formula for Lp norm(talking generally)? Is it?

Comment: I wrote a one-dimensional version of the loss function (and generalized the minimum away from the origin); it's the easiest way to understand the point being made in the quote

Answer (score 1):

In $L_1$ you need to take absolute values.

What you're mentioning is most likely a fact that $\|x\|_2 \leq \|x\|_1$.

To see this note that $\sum{|x_i|^2} \leq (\sum{|x_i|})^2$ (because quadratic function is convex).

Comment: I did mention the square root of x1^2+x2^2....xn^2 in L2 . However, I forget to mention the absolute values of elements of the vector X in L1

Comment: Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**strong text**
As you see in the graph below, |w| will give same value. for example |+/- 0.001| = 0.001.
Now for the square(w), the 0.001^2 is too low, so its slow until it reaches certain point, later the square part will accelerate the value. so thats why at the near origin |w| faster than square(w)